# Ciclo FOR, extraña sintáxis

Tags: jquery

¿De qué forma en JQuery se puede usar un FOR como el siguiente?

```
for(property in value){}
```

Tenía entendido que el `for` debía tener la siguiente estructura

```
for(var i=0;i>=algo.lenght;i++){}
```

Comment: Los dos son iteradores pero en la primera iteras en las propiedades de un objeto y en la segunda iteras en un objeto `tipo-arreglo` ([`arguments`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Funciones/arguments) es uno de ellos). Recuerda que los arreglos también son objetos pero no es recomendable usar la primera variante en ellos.

Comment: Las 2 sentencias que estás mostrando no son de jQuery sino de JavaScript. Para `for`...`in` la referencia está en https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Sentencias/for...in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Todas las respuestas anteriores son válidas cuando se trata de iterar sobre arrays, pero la sintaxis `for...in` **es válida para objetos**.

Extraigamos un ejemplo de la documentación de for...in en [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in#Examples):

```
var obj = {a:1, b:2, c:3};

for (var prop in obj) {
  console.log("obj." + prop + " = " + obj[prop]);
}
// resultado: obj.a = 1, obj.b = 2, obj.c = 3
```

Pero la documentación es muy clara advirtiendo que esto iteraría sobre **todas** las propiedades de un objeto, incluyendo sus ancestros (o prototipos, *clases* de las que deriva), para iterar solamente sobre las propiedades asignadas al objeto en sí y no las que hereda, debes usar el método `.hasOwnProperty( name )`

```
var triangle = {a:1, b:2, c:3};

function ColoredTriangle() {
  this.color = "red";
}

ColoredTriangle.prototype = triangle;

// las propiedades del triangle son del prototipo, no de la instancia "obj"

var obj = new ColoredTriangle();

for (var prop in obj) {
  if( obj.hasOwnProperty( prop ) ) {
    console.log("obj." + prop + " = " + obj[prop]);
  } 
}

// Output:
// "obj.color = red"
```

De hecho hay una respuesta sumamente popular en StackOverflow sobre este tema, que no es exclusivo de jQuery sino vale para todo el lenguaje JavaScript: https://stackoverflow.com/a/684692/1778979

Answer (score 4):

Podrias usar el [$.each()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/)

```
$.each(obj, function( key, value ) {
  alert( key + ": " + value );
});
```

de esta forma iteras cada elemento, pero no iteras propiedades sino elementos del array o lista

Answer (score 1):

en este link puedes observar la manera en la que se usa.
https://api.jquery.com/each/

Ahora un for each como se le conoce, itera sobre una lista de objetos, por ejemplo:

Tengo una lista "A" que contiene los objetos A1, A2, A3 y A4.

Con un for each puedo acceder a cada uno de los objetos que se encuentren contenidos en la lista A sin tener que declarar la posición en la lista o arreglo.

Answer (score 0):

La sintaxis que muestras del for no funciona, o al menos creo que no habrían iteraciones, lo correcto sería:

```
for (var i = 0; i < algo.length; ++i) {}
```

---

En cuanto a jQuery y solo para agregar a los otras dos respuestas que ya responden a la pregunta, **hay otro método que sirve para iterar una colección jQuery** (en el contexto de la pregunta no dice exactamente sobre qué se quiere iterar), este método es [.each()](http://api.jquery.com/each/), no hay que confundirlo con el de las otras dos respuestas ([$.each()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) es para arrays y objetos):

```
<ul>
  <li>Comer</li>
  <li>Dormir</li>
  <li>Programar</li>
</ul>


$( "li" ).each(function( index ) {
  console.log( index + ": " + $( this ).text() );
});
```

---

Si deseas incluso más información o posibilidades para realizar iteraciones, puedes mirar este enlace de la documentación de jQuery: https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/iterating/

Comment: Sería bueno conocer el motivo del voto negativo...

Comment: Yo no soy quién votó negativamente, pero van dos respuestas al porqué: 1) no está respondiendo como se usa for..in que es lo que el OP preguntó, y 2) no es correcta desde que escribes "no funciona", cuando la documentación de MDN claramente muestra que sí, además de arrays, JavaScript tiene objetos ;-)

Comment: Al parecer no respondo a la pregunta, eso parece ser cierto, sin embargo, cuando me refiero a que no funciona es que la propiedad "lenght" no existe. Creo que así como está planteada la segunda línea en la pregunta no va a funcionar.